# Dependency problem: libcurl4-openssl-dev vs libcurl4-gnutls-dev

Tags: ros, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS fuerte on 12.04 depends on libcurl4-openssl-dev, however most of the standard packages in ubuntu including the one I want to use now (libdap-dev/libgdal1-dev) depend on libcurl4-gnutls-dev.

These two packages are mutually exclusive and I have not found a solution out of this dependency conflict.

Has anybody found a solution to this problem? Would it be feasible to change ROS to depend on libcurl4-gnutls-dev instead?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34495/dependency-problem:-libcurl4-openssl-dev-vs-libcurl4-gnutls-dev/) by [smash0190](https://answers.ros.org/users/1606/smash0190/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2012-05-21

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-05-21**:
I've had the same issue on one of my machines. Both packages provide "libcurl-dev" (or "libcurl-ssl-dev") virtual package, so maybe ROS could depend on that so that it wouldn't matter which package was installed, as long as at least one was.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-05-21**:
+1 (@Eric Perko)

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2012-06-05**:
I just got bitten by this. I need libgdal1-dev but installing that will remove the fuerte packages. Any suggestions of how to work around this?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-06-05**:
You could try compiling the packages that depend on libcurl4-openssl-dev (I think it's only the resource_retriever package and anything that depends on resource_retriever) with libcurl4-gnutls-dev installed... maybe it would just work if you compiled it against the other version?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-07-13**:
For a little background on this issue, see http://curl.haxx.se/legal/distro-dilemma.html

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-07-15**:
Thanks for the background info, @Eric! What I understand from this discussion is that whenever possible, one should use the gnutls variant, since the openssl variant is only there for backward compatibility. Is that correct? Should someone open a bug report on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it mainly depends on licensing and the fact that OpenSSL and GNUTLS don't have exactly the same feature sets. If your code is BSD, you have no issue using the OpenSSL version. I think the real problem is that they can't be installed side-by-side because they have the same .so names...

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0